# Is there a way to merge a source branch into a target branch while preserving commits at the HEAD of the target branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

If you have a `target` branch that looks like this, for example

```
o---o---o---o
a   b   c   d
```

But a `source` branch that looks like this (e.g., does not contain the commit `d`)

```
o---o---o---o---o---o
a   b   c   e   f   g
```

Is there a way to merge `source` into `target` such that commits in `target` that are not in `source` are kept at the `HEAD` of target? So the `target` branch would look like afterwards

```
o---o---o---o---o---o---o
a   b   c   e   f   g   d
```

I'm not too worried about merge conflicts as I know `d` should not conflict with any commits being merged from `source`

Comment: As a side comment, branches do not have a `HEAD`. That sounds like svn jargon applied to git. In git, `HEAD` is _always_ where you are (which not necessarily is it a branch).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but you need to rewrite history of `target`:

```
git checkout target
git rebase source
```

That would do it. And, well.... you are not really merging, in case it's not obvious.

Comment: How would _that_ change target to look like the diagram?

Comment: What do you mean? The way rebase works, it will checkout g (the tip of source) and it will cherry-pick d (the only revision from target that is missing from source) moving target to the new revision d (well, `d'`, actually).